# Administrator role can't edit html source in tinymce

Tags: 6

I have created and administrator role that has full HTML editing capabilities when creating a node. The issue I am having is that when they click on the button to edit html source button (in tinymce) the resulting dialog doesn't show any source. As user 1, this works with no issues. I thought this was a permission issue of some sort but I can't find where this would be set. This is on a Drupal 6 install. Can anyone tell me what I need to do (and where to go) to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue is that the person logging in as an administrator was using Internet Explorer 11. Once they changed browsers to either Firefox or Chrome, everything worked as it should. Microsoft should really get out of the browser business.